# Test integrity of ZIP file?

Tags: zip

Near as I can tell the zip -T option only determines if files can be extracted -- it doesn't really test the archive for internal integrity. For example, I deliberately corrupted the local (not central directory) CRC for a file, and zip didn't care at all, reporting the archive as OK. Is there some other utility to do this?

There's a lot of internal redundancy in ZIP files, and it would be nice to have a way of checking it all. Of course, normally the central directory is all you need, but when repairing a corrupted archive often all you have is a fragment, with the central directory clobbered or missing. I'd like to know if archives I create are as recoverable as possible.

Comment: What about `unzip -t`?

Comment: Same behavior as zip.

Comment: `unzip -t` could be an option, but what if we need to use the Alpine Linux unzip where -t option is not available?

Answer (score 51):

> unzip -t
>
> Test archive files.
>
> This option extracts each specified file in memory and compares the CRC (cyclic redundancy check, an enhanced checksum) of the expanded file with the original's stored CRC value.

[ source: https://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip ]

Comment: There are 2 CRCs per file: local and central. `unzip -t` only tests the latter.

Comment: i don't know what you mean by "local" versus "central" (central to what?) but when i run "unzip -t myzip_file.zip" i see a line output for commenting on the integrity of each and every zipped file, like (imagine better formatting): "testing:  AARiseTransitSet.cpp     OK
    testing: AARiseTransitSet.h       OK
    testing: AASaturn.cpp             OK
    testing: AASaturn.h               OK
    ...

Comment: Not the place to explain internal structure of ZIP files. Wikepedia article is pretty good on this. As I said, it is a misleading report that you are seeing.

Comment: If i go into a zip file with a hex-editor and change one byte, then i see for one file:   testing: AA_sphere.htm                  bad CRC 7952862e  (should be 44c6f7f8) while the rest are listed as "OK".  you'll continue to declare this as "misleading", but that's exactly what i expect for a file-by-file CRC check of a zip file.  now... good luck to you Sir.

Comment: I think you have changed the central directory CRC, at the end. Try changing the local one, before or after the file.

Answer (score 33):

Using [Info-ZIP](http://infozip.sourceforge.net/), attempting to fix an archive will compare the local and central CRCs, and combining that with archive tests will allow all the CRCs to be checked. If you run

```
unzip -t archive.zip
```

*and*

```
zip -F archive.zip --out archivefix.zip
```

and neither complain, that means the archive’s contents match both the central and local CRCs. (You can delete `archivefix.zip` afterwards.)

To verify this, starting with the Info-ZIP source code for `zip` 3.0, I created a file as follows:

```
zip -9 test.zip zip.txt zipup.c
```

I then corrupted the central directory CRC for `zip.txt` by changing the byte at offset 0xB137. I got the opposite behaviour to what you observed; `unzip -v` reported the altered CRC from the central directory, but `unzip -t` and `zip -T` reported that the file was OK (checking against the local CRC).

But running

```
zip -F test --out testfix
```

reported

```
Fix archive (-F) - assume mostly intact archive
Zip entry offsets do not need adjusting
 copying: zip.txt
        zip warning: Local Entry CRC does not match CD: zip.txt
 copying: zipup.c
```

The "corrected" file still listed the altered CRC for `zip.txt`.

Altering the local CRC for `zip.txt` at offset 0x10 caused both `unzip -t` and `zip -T` to report a CRC error, but `zip -F` didn't spot anything wrong.

Thus from my experiments, mismatches between an archive entry's contents and its CRCs can be detected as follows:

- local only: `zip -T` and `unzip -t`; `zip -F` will also complain about the local-central mismatch
- local and central: `zip -T` and `unzip -t`
- central only: `zip -T` and `unzip -t` will not complain, but `zip -F` will indicate a local-central mismatch

(Note that by default `zip -T` simply uses `unzip -tqq`, so `zip -T` and `unzip -t` really are equivalent. You can read the `unzip` source code to check that testing an archive really compares the local CRC, not the central one; look for `extract_or_test_files()`, `extract_or_test_entrylist()` and `extract_or_test_member()`, all in `extract.c`.)

Comment: Complicated. And no doubt very dependent on what versions (GNU, BSD, etc.) And CRC is only one of the numerous integrity checks that can be performed.

Comment: There aren't many versions of `zip` and `unzip` available on Unix-like platforms; Info-ZIP is used pretty much everywhere...

Comment: As far as it being complicated, it takes just two commands; if both `unzip -t` and `zip -F` run without error, you're OK and both CRCs have been checked.

Comment: Thanks! Will check this out. Also, forgot to mention: ZIP files are ZIP64.

Comment: Answers like this should be golden standard on this website: a thorough research, including experiments and digging through source code, summed up in a concise manner.

Comment: I have an archive where the process described here is producing a slightly smaller zip file without "reporting any issue" as exit code or in the output. So to "check integrity this way you might want to compare the size of the produced file with the original one.

Comment: @karfau that’s interesting — does the smaller archive still contain all the files present in the original?

Comment: @StephenKitt yes, I'm not sure what went wrong, but the file was supposed to have even more files in it and was somehow not complete when being zipped or transferred. Sadly I can not offer to share the file, but if you want me to run any commands on it and send you the output, let me know.

Comment: @karfau and `unzip -t` doesn’t complain?

Comment: @StephenKitt yes, that one is not indicating any issue.

Comment: @karfau I suspect that your archive has unused data at the end — what does `cmp origarchive.zip smallerarchive.zip` say?

Comment: @StephenKitt `origarchive.zip smallerarchive.zip differ: byte 7, line1`

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have a look at `zipdetails`. From its man page:

> Zipdetails displays information about the internal record structure of
> the zip file. It is not concerned with displaying any details of the
> compressed data stored in the zip file.

I do not know if `zipdetails` will detect inconsistencies, but it should help you in finding/understanding inconsistencies. Here's a small sample from its output:

```
00000 LOCAL HEADER #1       04034B50
00004 Extract Zip Spec      14 '2.0'
00005 Extract OS            00 'MS-DOS'
00006 General Purpose Flag  0808
      [Bits 1-2]            0 'Normal Compression'
      [Bit  3]              1 'Streamed'
      [Bit 11]              1 'Language Encoding'
00008 Compression Method    0008 'Deflated'
0000A Last Mod Time         5352884C 'Mon Oct 18 17:02:24 2021'
0000E CRC                   00000000
00012 Compressed Length     00000000
00016 Uncompressed Length   00000000
0001A Filename Length       000B
0001C Extra Length          0000
0001E Filename              'graphic.svg'
00029 PAYLOAD

02947 STREAMING DATA HEADER 08074B50
0294B CRC                   C622C669
0294F Compressed Length     0000291E
02953 Uncompressed Length   0002F706
```

I can also confirm this bit from the man page:

> Error handling is still a work in progress.  If the program encounters
> a problem reading a zip file it is likely to terminate with an
> unhelpful error message.

Comment: `zipdetails` is indeed a useful tool; while it doesn’t *flag* inconsistencies, it does display both the local and central CRCs, and those values can be compared manually.